# Manually bootstrapping linear regression in R

Tags: r, regression, lm, statistics-bootstrap

|Hi guys,
I am asking you for help as I am stucked with bootstrapping...

The task is:
*Use the nonparametric bootstrap to compute bootstrap standard error of CAPM beta estimate based on 1000 bootstrap replications and bootstrap sample size equal to the size of the original sample.*

If I understand it correctly, I am supposed to run my regression model 1000 times to estimate different estimates of the beta and its standard error. However, I am not able to put my thoughts into an actual R code.

My code:

```
#1)fetch data from Yahoo
#AAPL prices
apple08 <- getSymbols('AAPL', auto.assign = FALSE, from = '2008-1-1', to = 
"2008-12-31")[,6]
#market proxy
rm08<-getSymbols('^ixic', auto.assign = FALSE, from = '2008-1-1', to = 
"2008-12-31")[,6]

#log returns of AAPL and market
logapple08<- na.omit(ROC(apple08)*100)
logrm08<-na.omit(ROC(rm08)*100)

#OLS for beta estimation
beta_AAPL_08<-summary(lm(logapple08~logrm08))$coefficients[2,1]
```

OK, I've got the coefficient estimate of AAPL beta for '08. Now, I would like to run bootstrap on the beta and its standard error 1000 times with the sample size same as the original.

```
set.seed(666)
Boot_times=1000
mean.boot=rep(0,Boot_times)
for(i in 1:Boot_times){
# nonparametric bootstrap
data.boot=#Here I am stucked, I dunno what to put here
boot[i]=data.boot
}
```

I have thought about using

```
summary(lm(sample(logapple08, size=length(logapple08), replace = 
TRUE)~sample(logrm08, size=length(logrm08), replace = 
TRUE)))$coefficients[2,1]
```

However I guess it is not correct. I do resample the returns, however I assume that it resamples the data withouth taking care of the dates of the returns, i.e. it regresses for instance AAPL return from 25/1/08 to a market's return which happened on 25/2/08.

Help would be appreciated, thank you!

Adam

Comment: I think if you ask this question on `cross val` , you get more chance in a decent answer

Answer (score 1):

In order to bootstrap a linear regrassion computed with `lm` you can do something following the lines of the code below.

```
library(boot)

# This is the function 'statistic'    
boot_lm_coef <- function(data, index){
    coef(lm(logapple08 ~ logrm08, data = data[index, ]))[2]
}

df_boot <- data.frame(logapple08, logrm08)

set.seed(666)
Boot_times <- 1000
result <- boot(df_boot, boot_lm_coef, R = Boot_times)
mean(result$t)
#[1] 1.078191
```

Notes:

1. I have used `coef`, not `summary(lm(.))[2, 1]` which is overkill
2. The data must be a `data.frame` for `lm` to work.

Answer (score 0):

In case you (or someone else) did not wish to do this manually, there is also `model_parameters` function from `parameters` to get bootstrapped confidence intervals and p-values

```r
library(parameters)

mod <- lm(formula = wt ~ mpg, data = mtcars)

model_parameters(mod)
#> Parameter   | Coefficient |   SE |         95% CI | t(30) |      p
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------
#> (Intercept) |        6.05 | 0.31 | [ 5.42,  6.68] | 19.59 | < .001
#> mpg         |       -0.14 | 0.01 | [-0.17, -0.11] | -9.56 | < .001

model_parameters(mod, bootstrap = TRUE, iterations = 100)
#> Parameter   | Coefficient |         95% CI |     p
#> --------------------------------------------------
#> (Intercept) |        5.99 | [ 5.36,  6.68] | 0.010
#> mpg         |       -0.14 | [-0.17, -0.11] | 0.010
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>