# How to use the replicate function in R to repeat the function

Tags: r, loops, replicate

I have a problem when using `replicate` to repeat the function.

I tried to use the bootstrap to fit 
a quadratic model using concentration as the predictor and Total_lignin as the response and going to report an estimate of the maximum with a corresponding standard error.

My idea is to create a function called bootFun that essentially did everything within one iteration of a for loop. bootFun took in only the data set the predictor, and the response to use (both variable names in quotes).

However, the SD is 0, not correct. I do not know where is the wrong place. Could you please help me with it?

```
# Load the libraries
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

# Read the .csv and only use M.giganteus and S.ravennae.
dat <- read_csv('concentration.csv') %>% 
  filter(variety == 'M.giganteus' | variety == 'S.ravennae') %>% 
  arrange(variety)
# Check the data
head(dat)

# sample size
n <- nrow(dat)

# A function to do one iteration
bootFun <- function(dat, pred, resp){
  # Draw the sample size from the dataset
  sample <- sample_n(dat, n, replace = TRUE)

  # A quadratic model fit
  formula <- paste0('resp', '~', 'pred', '+', 'I(pred^2)')
  fit <- lm(formula, data = sample)

  # Derive the max of the value of concentration
  max <- -fit$coefficients[2]/(2*fit$coefficients[3])

  return(max)
}

max <- bootFun(dat = dat, pred = 'concentration', resp = 'Total_lignin' )

# Iterated times
N <- 5000

# Use 'replicate' function to do a loop
maxs <- replicate(N, max)

# An estimate of the max of predictor and corresponding SE
mean(maxs)
sd(maxs)
```

Comment: Welcome! Please provide `dput(dat)`, needless to say that we cannot access your .csv file. Read here how we ask reproducible questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610

Comment: You're replicating the *result* of a *single* function call N times, not replicating the function call N times.

Comment: `maxs <- replicate(N, bootFun (...))`

Comment: See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47578665/8245406).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base package `boot`, function `boot`, can ease the job of calling the bootstrap function repeatedly. The first argument must be the data set, the second argument is an indices argument, that the user *does not set* and other arguments can also be passed toit. In this case those other arguments are the predictor and the response names.

```
library(boot)

bootFun <- function(dat, indices, pred, resp){
  # Draw the sample size from the dataset
  dat.sample <- dat[indices, ]

  # A quadratic model fit
  formula <- paste0(resp, '~', pred, '+', 'I(', pred, '^2)')
  formula <- as.formula(formula)
  fit <- lm(formula, data = dat.sample)

  # Derive the max of the value of concentration
  max <- -fit$coefficients[2]/(2*fit$coefficients[3])

  return(max)
}

N <- 5000
set.seed(1234)  # Make the bootstrap results reproducible

results <- boot(dat, bootFun, R = N, pred = 'concentration', resp = 'Total_lignin')

results
#
#ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
#
#
#Call:
#boot(data = dat, statistic = bootFun, R = N, pred = "concentration", 
#    resp = "Total_lignin")
#
#
#Bootstrap Statistics :
#      original        bias    std. error
#t1* -0.4629808 -0.0004433889  0.03014259
#


results$t0  # this is the statistic, not bootstrapped
#concentration 
#   -0.4629808

mean(results$t)  # bootstrap value
#[1] -0.4633233
```

Note that to fit a polynomial, function `poly` is much simpler than to explicitly write down the polynomial terms one by one.

```
formula <- paste0(resp, '~ poly(', pred, ',2, raw = TRUE)')
```

Check the distribution of the bootstrapped statistic.

```
op <- par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
hist(results$t)
qqnorm(results$t)
qqline(results$t)
par(op)
```

[image]

**Test data**

```
set.seed(2020)  # Make the results reproducible
x <- cumsum(rnorm(100))
y <- x + x^2 + rnorm(100)
dat <- data.frame(concentration = x, Total_lignin = y)
```